# Block exchange users from printing emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, printing, exchange

We are looking at reducing office costs, and one thing our users tend to do is needlessly print emails.
We use MS Outlook 2007 with Exchange Server 2003. Is there any possible way to prevent users from being able to print their emails?

Comment: to put it simply no. Even if there is, they can just screen shot it and paste it to paint or copy and paste the contents to word/notepad/wordpad and print it.

Comment: @Kyle, I know we can't absolutely prevent it, but most of the people we are targeting would never go through those steps to print anyways. Mostly I'm just focusing on Outlook. We just need to make the electronic methods of archiving their messages the 'easy' way.

Comment: Unless of course you stop them from printing at all.

Comment: What a horrible idea. If you want a way to piss people off, this would be it

Comment: @d03boy, i'm in IT, everyone already hates me. Besides times are tough, management was just curious if it was a policy that could be enforced systematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kyle says, people will figure out how to get around it.

Myself, I can't think of any way to make the system printer(s) not available to only certain applications (especially MS applications like Outlook running on Windows).

If you can't take away their printers, then "people policies" are probably your best bet.  "New Company Policy: Keep needlessly printing emails and we'll fire you" generally keeps people from printing emails. :)

Comment: A common business solution is to charge departments or individuals for paper and sometimes toner.